# Induction proof for Taylor series $e^x$

Tags: calculus, induction, taylor-expansion

I need to prove by induction that the series
$$
1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} \cdots = e^x 
$$
I tried two approaches, both of which showed to be a dead end. Does anyone know how?

EDIT: Here is the least objectionable approach.
Prove for x=0
$$
1 = e^0    true
$$

Assume true for x=p
$$
1 + p + \frac{p^2}{2!} + \frac{p^3}{3!} \cdots = e^p 
$$
Prove for x=p+1
$$
1 + p+1 + \frac{(p+1)^2}{2!} + \frac{(p+1)^3}{3!} \cdots = e^{(p+1)}
$$
Expanding these espressions leads to complications.

Comment: On this site, you are supposed to show your approaches so people can help you best.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the definition of Taylor series?

Comment: use the product for the exponential function (wit finite n) $ e^{x} = (1+x/n)^{n} $

Comment: In some books, this is the _definition_ of $e^x$. In others, $e^x$ is defined by virtue of being its own derivative. You could also first define the _number_ $e$, however you wish to do that, then use the concept of general real exponentials, however you define those, to define the function $e^x$. There are other ways to go about this as well, and they all require different approaches. What is _your_ definition of $e^x$?

Comment: **How do you define $e^x$?** We can't help you unless you provide this.

Comment: Btw you are trying to use induction, which will help only with  positive integer values of $x$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Depends on what you're inducting on. If your definition of $e^x$ is that it is equal to its own derivative, then inducting not on $x$, but on the degree of the terms on the left-hand side is a natrual thing to do. Then it would be valid for all $x$.

Comment: @Arthur: got your point. I was however referring to the way OP used induction on $x$ and not on number of terms in series. Btw OP has still not given his definition of $e^x$ which can help people to answer the question more effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** you can use that $f(x) = e^x$ verifies $f' = f$, you can prove easily by induction that
$$\forall n\in\Bbb N:\ f^{(n)} = f,$$
so the Taylor series of $f$ at $0$ will be
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
**But** you **also** need prove that the Taylor series converges to $f$. In this case, this can be done easily studying the remainder, **but there are examples of functions with convergent Taylor series that $\not\to$ function**.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use the binomial theorem on

$$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

so you get

$$ e^x = \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\displaystyle {n\choose k}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^k$$

It isn't pretty, but it's a way to recover $e^x$ without the use of Taylor series.