# Proof that $\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^y y}{y!} = xe^{x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-sum

I am looking for an analytical proof that :
$$\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^y y}{y!} = xe^{x}$$

Both CAS [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=+Sum%5BDivide%5BPower%5Bx%2Cy%5D%2C+y%21%5Dy%2C%7By%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D) and sympy agree on the result :

```
from sympy import I, oo, Sum, exp, pi, factorial
from sympy.abc import y,x
print(Sum(y*x**y / factorial(y),(y,0,oo)).doit())
# prints x*exp(x)
```

but do not provide proof. I tried few things like substitution, exp/ln rewritting but ended up on undefined $1/factorial(-1)$

Comment: Did you mean to write $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{\color{red}k}x}{\color{red}k!}$?

Comment: Surely you want to take the summation over y. Just use the power series of the exponential (i.e. the most common definition), to see the result instantly.

Comment: Your question reduces to the well known identity $$e^x=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{x^k}{k!}.$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2265486/induction-proof-for-taylor-series-ex

Comment: Sorry made a typo in the latex equation. Now its ok and coherent with wolfram/sympy example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{x^k k}{k!}=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{x^k}{(k-1)!}=x\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=x\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{x^n}{n!}=xe^x.$$

Comment: Duh! I don't know why I tried to eliminate the cas k=0 only after substition, not before. indeed after the first equality it comes obvious.. Thanks !